# How to use Xpath with Nokogiri to print values when XML has namespaces

Tags: ruby, namespaces, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse the XML file below that has namespaces, but doc.xpath() and doc.search() don't print anything.

How to handle namespaces in order that doc.xpath() and doc.search() work?

So, having the below XML file only doc.css() works.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ff-rep:MNEVENTS xmlns="http://www.example.com/MN-EVENTS" 
xmlns:ff-rep="http://www.example.com/MN-EVENTS" 
xmlns:sub-ff="http://www.example.com/sub-ff" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/MN-EVENTS ff-rep.xsd">
 <FFEVENT>
    <Ini>00:10</Ini>
    <Code>MKK</Code>
    <Ver>5.09</Ver>
  </FFEVENT>
  <KUI>
    <Serial>IU00-35556</Serial>
    <SubS>8879-22V</SubS>
  </KUI>
  <KUI>
    <Serial>5561-PO2221</Serial>
    <SubS>9980-1M</SubS>
  </KUI>
</ff-rep:MNEVENTS>
```

but If I remove the "xmlns:...http.." references at the top from this

```xml
<ff-rep:MNEVENTS xmlns="http://www.example.com/MN-EVENTS" 
xmlns:ff-rep="http://www.example.com/MN-EVENTS" 
xmlns:sub-ff="http://www.example.com/sub-ff" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/MN-EVENTS ff-rep.xsd">
```

to this

```
<ff-rep:MNEVENTS>
```

`doc.xpath()` and `doc.search()` both work as expected.

The code I've been trying is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("input.xml"))

puts doc.search('//Serial') # It doesn't work with "xmlns:http.." references
puts doc.xpath('//Serial')  # It doesn't work with "xmlns:http.." references
puts doc.css("KUI Serial")  # It works with "xmlns:http.." references
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What about `puts doc.css('KUI>Serial')`?

Comment: Hello Charli, thanks for help. With doc.css() has always worked. The issue was only with doc.xpath() and doc.search().

Answer (score 3):

When there are namespaces in a XML-document XPath needs to know what schema you want to work on. In this case you can use `doc.xpath("//xmlns:Serial")`.

To make it a little easier Nokogiri has a method for removing all namespaces. This method should only be used if there is no chance of collision of elements with the same name but from different namespaces.

```
doc.remove_namespaces!
doc.xpath("//Serial")
```

Comment: Hello Pafjo, thanks for your answer. It works just fine how you said. removing namespaces first with "doc.remove_namespaces!" or with "doc.xpath("//xmlns:Serial")". Thanks for help others! Best regards

Comment: @zurix if this fixed the issue you should accept this as the answer.

Comment: Yes Charlie. I already answered to Pafjo to let him/anybody know that his answer was a nice solution to my question. Regards :)